# mounting windows share on ubuntu machine

Tags: 18.04, mount

I am working with Linux system and trying to mount a `windows share` on my Linux machine using the following command:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install cifs-utils
sudo su
mkdir /HPC-Archive
ls /HPC-Archive/
mount -t cifs -o user=my_user_name //windows_share_folder /my_mount_folder/
ls /HPC-Archive/ (to check if the windows share is mounted or not)
```

hen I run this command I will get this error:

```
mount error(5): Input/output error
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

do you know how to fix the problem?

Comment: Why do you create a directory `/HPC-Archive` that you do not use in the `mount`command?  Try replacing `/my_mount_folder` by `/HPC-Archive`.

Answer (score 0):

the man page of mount.cifs shows 
mount.cifs {service} {mount-point} [-o options]

service: using //server/share syntax
(the share part is missing in your mount command)
I assume /my_mount_folder = /HPC-Archive ?

options are allowed to precede the other parameters